# Access Denied in Internet Explorer when using iframe within page with different domain url

Tags: javascript, iframe, access-denied

I get the error Access Denied. i use iframe with different domain name. I can't touch the code of the iframe src . How can i fix it ?

Comment: Google for "same origin policy".

Answer (score 2):

You can't "fix" it. It's a security feature.

If you were a bit more specific as to what you're aiming to do, somebody might be able to come up with a workaround, though.